# Ended listener is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

This function works greatly only when in array *defaultArrayMelody* are different numbers - one after the other - I mean: [5, 3, 4, 2] - it works,
[5, 3, 3, 2] - it doesn't work.

I suspect 'ended' listener is performed twice and adding two event listeners to the  element. Then the function is looped and it doesn't work as I want. How to do to limit the pursuit of listeners to one?

Java Script:

```
function playDefault() {
const defaultArrayMelody = [70, 71, 69, 70];
const audio = defaultArrayMelody.map(el => document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${el}"]`));


for (let i = 0 ; i < defaultArrayMelody.length; ++i) {
    audio[i].addEventListener('ended', () => {

        const index = i + 1;
        if (index > audio.length-1) return false;
        audio[index].play();            
    });
}

audio[0].play();
}

document.querySelector(`#playDefault`).addEventListener('click', playDefault);
```

HTML:

```
<button class="button" id="playDefault">Play Default</button>
<audio data-key="67" src="sounds/c1.wav"></audio>...
```

Comment: I take it you actually want duplicates in the array

Comment: does [5,3,2,3] work?

Comment: are you sure? you'd still be adding 2 event listeners on the one audio

Comment: @JaromandaX I want two of the same elements performed one after another.

Comment: @JaromandaX, yes I am sure, but all audios loops in this case (from the beginning to the end), but if [5, 3, 2, 2] - 2 loops into infinity.

Comment: What you need to do is remove the `ended` event listener once it's triggered, because every time you play the audio, the ended event will be fired - I'm surprised in the case of 5,3,2,3 you don't get 5,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,3... etc or in the case of 3,2,3,5 you'd get 3,2+5,3,2+5 etc ... 2 and 5 starting simultaneously

Comment: note: chrome 55 and firefox 50 have an options parameter for addEventListener where you can add a "once" parameter to trigger once only - however, this still wouldn't help in the case of a pattern like 3,3,2,5 as the second 3 and the 2 would be started simultaneously if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @JaromandaX You can put the source code? I still don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once an ended listener fires you need to remove it, so it wont get fired again

However, the way you are adding the event listeners, (all at once, basically) means that you've already added multiple listeners to the audio that gets played multiple times, so if the repeated audio isn't the last one in the array, you'll get some issues, no doubt

The ideal solution is to add the listener only once the audio starts, and remove the listener once the `ended` event fires.

> These answers INCLUDE the request in the comment for an optional "pause" between audio element playback - this is signified by a **negative** number in the `defaultArrayMelody`

```
function playDefault() {
    const defaultArrayMelody = [70, 71, -1000, 69, 70];
    const audio = defaultArrayMelody.map(el => el < 0 ? -el : document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${el}"]`));

    var playAudio = function(index) {
        if (audio[index]) {
            var listener = function() {
                this.removeEventListener('ended', listener);
                playAudio(index + 1);
            };
            if (typeof audio[index] == 'number') {
                setTimeout(() => playAudio(index + 1), audio[index]);
            } else {
                audio[index].addEventListener('ended', listener);
                audio[index].play();
            }
        }
    };
    playAudio(0);
}
document.querySelector(`#playDefault`).addEventListener('click', playDefault);
```

An alternative method would be to use Promise

```
function playDefault() {
    const defaultArrayMelody = [70, 71, -1000, 69, 70];
    const audio = defaultArrayMelody.map(el => el < 0 ? -el : document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${el}"]`));

    audio.reduce((prev, item) => prev.then(() => new Promise(resolve => {
        var listener = function listener() {
            this.removeEventListener('ended', listener);
            resolve();
        };
        if (typeof item== 'number') {
            setTimeout(resolve, item); // item is millseconds
        } else {
            item.addEventListener('ended', listener);
            item.play();
        }
    })), Promise.resolve());
}
document.querySelector(`#playDefault`).addEventListener('click', playDefault);
```

Here, you may get away with not removing the event listener, as the only thing the event listener does is resolve the promise - and once a promise is resolved, it can't be resolved (or rejected) again - thus ensuring the sequence plays in order only once. However, in the above code I included the removeEventListener ... without it, the code looks like

```
function playDefault() {
    const defaultArrayMelody = [70, 71, -1000, 69, 70];
    const audio = defaultArrayMelody.map(el => el < 0 ? -el : document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${el}"]`));

    audio.reduce((prev, item) => prev.then(() => new Promise(resolve => {
        if (typeof item== 'number') {
            setTimeout(resolve, item); // item is millseconds
        } else {
            item.addEventListener('ended', resolve);
            item.play();
        }
    })), Promise.resolve());
}
document.querySelector(`#playDefault`).addEventListener('click', playDefault);
```

Comment: All methods are working! Do you know how to do to add a second pause between some elements? 
My solution is add 0 to array. And in html: <audio data-key="0" src="duration_1s_file.wav"></audio>
Is there any better way? I suspect I will probably need split array for the other two.

Comment: @Garrs - I've edited the answer (it was getting a bit long) to include a possible method of including a pause between elements - see the code changes - hope this helps you in some way